# DynamicModule updating unexpectedly

Tags: dynamic

I have cut down a DynamicModule that was updating unexpectedly and found the following behaviour I don' t understand.

If I do this I get one random value as expected

```
Dynamic[
 th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
 th
]
```

In this case I also get one value as expected

```
DynamicModule[{th},
 Dynamic[ RandomReal[{-1, 1}]]
]
```

However, in this case the value is updating continuously. I did not expect this.

```
DynamicModule[{th},
 Dynamic[
  th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  th
 ]
]
```

Why does it do this and how do I make it give me just one value?

Edit

Here is a fuller example to show what I am aiming for. The DynamicModule has two parts that are wrapped in Dynamic and information from the first (set up and calculation) must be shared with the second (graphics).

```
DynamicModule[{th, ft, rr = 1, f = 0.2345, m, c, x, res},
 Column[{
   Row[{Slider[Dynamic[rr], {0, 10}], " ran amp = ", Dynamic[rr]}],
   Dynamic[
    th = Table[ 
      Cos[2 \[Pi] f (n - 1)] + RandomReal[{-rr, rr}], {n, 400}];
    ft = Fourier[th, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
    res = FindFit[Abs[ft[[1 ;; 200]]], m x + c, {c, m}, x];
    {m, c} /. res
    ],
   Dynamic[
    ListPlot[Abs[ft[[1 ;; 200]]], PlotRange -> All,
     ImageSize -> 5 72, 
     Epilog -> {Line[{{1, c}, {200, m 200 + c}} /. res]}]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: Try `DynamicModule[{th}, Dynamic[th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  th, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]`

Comment: @esprit Thank you for your comment. This works but my problem is more complicated. I have added an example to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation of the behavior

First, let me dispense with the OP's second example.  I assume `RandomReal[{-1, 1}]` is treated as *not* depending on any symbol (except possibly `RandomReal`, although I would not be surprised if `Protected` symbols were excluded from dynamic tracking).  So unlike `Clock`, `RandomReal` will not cause an update merely because it will probably return a different answer each time.  For this reason, the OP's second example is unproblematic.

This baffled me because at first I expected the first of the OP's examples to update continually.  For instance, this seemingly unimportant modification does update continually:

```
Dynamic[
 th;                       (* a1 *)
 th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]; (* a2 *)
 th                        (* a3 *)
 ]
```

The way I explain it to myself is this. I will compare it with the OP's first example, with the lines of code identified for convenient reference.

```
Dynamic[
 th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]; (* b1 *)
 th                        (* b2 *)
 ]
```

Determining when an update is triggered comes down (it seems) to whether an assignment would alter the result of executing the code again.  (Keep in mind that I'm assuming `RandomReal` is treated as if it gave the same value for the same input.)  In my example, line `a2` changes `th`, which means the previous line `a1` would have a different result.  This triggers an update.  In the OP's example, the assignment in line `b1` has no such effect.  The symbol `th` appears only after the assignment, so no update is necessary.

In the interest of efficiency, there may be a limit to how precisely *Mathematica* can determine the dependency of a code segment on a symbol.  In such cases, I would expect *Mathematica* to be conservative and assume that a update should be done.

This analyis has a bearing on the main question, which for me is, *Why does wrapping the first of the OP's examples inside a `DynamicModule` makes a difference?*

Strictly speaking it is not merely `DynamicModule`.  The following does not update continually:

```
DynamicModule[{},
 Dynamic[
  th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  th
 ]]
```

It has to do with `th` being a `DynamicModule` variable.  As such, [it is owned by the Front End](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#368838921).  If we look at the cell expressions of the two examples, we will see something important:

```
(* No DynamicModule example (OP's 1st) *)

Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicBox[ToBoxes[$CellContext`th = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]; $CellContext`th, StandardForm],
  ImageSizeCache->{95., {1., 13.}}]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.603873092328042*^9}]

(* DynamicModule example (OP's 3rd) *)

Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`th$$ = -0.014046062447770069`}, 
  DynamicBox[
   ToBoxes[$CellContext`th$$ = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]; $CellContext`th$$, 
    StandardForm],
   ImageSizeCache->{118., {1., 13.}}],
  DynamicModuleValues:>{}]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.6038735203232813`*^9}]
```

Note that the current value of `th` is stored in the `DynamicModule` expression maintained by the Front End.  The initialization (in the second line) is like line `a1` above; it is evaluated first.  At first, the line is simply

```
 DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`th$$},
```

in which case it is just like the line `a1`.  The value of `th` will be changed when the Front End sends the body of the `DynamicModule` to Kernel for evaluation.  This change will trigger another update, just as in my first "`a`" example above.  That's why, I think, that the OP's third example updates continually.

### Fix of the OP's last example

Personally, I would probably use [esprit's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5861/esprit) `TrackedSymbols` solution, perhaps with [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refresh.html).  For the sake of offering a complete answer, here's another way:

```
DynamicModule[{th, ft, rr, f, m, c, x, res, updateRR},
 Column[{
   Row[{Slider[Dynamic[rr, updateRR], {0, 10}], " ran amp = ", Dynamic[rr]}],
   Dynamic[{m, c} /. res],
   Dynamic[
    ListPlot[Abs[ft[[1 ;; 200]]], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 5 * 72,
      Epilog -> {Line[{{1, c}, {200, m 200 + c}} /. res]}]
    ]
   }],
 Initialization :> (
   rr = 1;
   f = 0.2345;
   updateRR = (rr = #;
      th = Table[Cos[2 π f (n - 1)] + RandomReal[{-rr, rr}], {n, 400}];
      ft = Fourier[th, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
      res = FindFit[Abs[ft[[1 ;; 200]]], m x + c, {c, m}, x]) &;
   updateRR[rr])
 ]
```

The trick is to update the symbols that depend only on `rr` at the time `rr` is updated, using the second argument of [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html).

Comment: Many thanks for this I understand much more now. The key statement for me was "...whether an assignment would alter the result of executing the code again." This is an important rule that I had not spotted elsewhere. Your alternative solution using Initialization is also a construct I have not used before. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for a great question.  `Dynamic` is complicated and subtle, but it's not often these days that such a clear and straightforward question about `Dynamic` makes me have to think, explore, and figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, is this what you need ?

```
DynamicModule[{th, ft, rr = 1, f = 0.2345, m, c, x, res}, 
  Column[{Row[{Slider[Dynamic[rr], {0, 10}], " ran amp = ", Dynamic[rr]}], 
    Dynamic[th = Table[Cos[2 \[Pi] f (n - 1)] + RandomReal[{-rr, rr}], {n, 400}];
     ft = Fourier[th, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
      res = FindFit[Abs[ft[[1 ;; 200]]], m x + c, {c, m}, x];
        {m, c} /. res, 

    TrackedSymbols :> {rr}

    ], 
    Dynamic[ListPlot[Abs[ft[[1 ;; 200]]], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 5 72, 
      Epilog -> {Line[{{1, c}, {200, m 200 + c}} /. res]}]]}]]
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution works well. I have a new understanding.